# How to get textbox value in to another page... php / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, textbox

I need to get textbox value to another php page. By clicking 'Box' icon i want to submit perticular row only. I already got row ID to 'Box' icon. How can i do that with the while loop.

[image]

thanks in advance

Tharindu

Comment: can i get something more clear about what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

In the original php file generate a different html form for each box.

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
    <input name="Z067DA" />
</form>
```

In the page2.php file use code similar to this. $value contains the user
submitted information.

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
    // Use submitted value.
}
```

If you know the input tag names in advance you can just access them directly in your php code.

```
$value = $_POST['Z067DA'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should arrange the HTML code for this in the following fashion:

```
    <table>
      <form method="post">
      <tr>
         <td>Z0678<input type="hidden" name="id" value="Z0678"></td><td><input type="text" value="0" name="qty"></td><td><input type="image" src="box.gif"></td>
      </tr>
      </form>
<form method="post">
      <tr>
         <td>Z0678<input type="hidden" name="id" value="Z0678"></td><td><input type="text" value="0" name="qty"></td><td><input type="image" src="box.gif"></td>
      </tr>
      </form>
<form method="post">
      <tr>
         <td>Z0678<input type="hidden" name="id" value="Z0678"></td><td><input type="text" value="0" name="qty"></td><td><input type="image" src="box.gif"></td>
      </tr>
      </form>
<form method="post">
      <tr>
         <td>Z0678<input type="hidden" name="id" value="Z0678"></td><td><input type="text" value="0" name="qty"></td><td><input type="image" src="box.gif"></td>
      </tr>
      </form>
</table>
```

Then once you hit the image, it will submit the form. Add this code to the top of your PHP script "`<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` and you will see that you can now process the posted contents based on the data that was posted without the need for any while loop.

Answer (score 0):

let the you have posted be list.php

in the text box like

```
<input type=text name="rid" value= " <?php echo $rid ?>" onclick="location.href='view.php'"/>
```

get the row id in next page that is view.php

```
 $id = $_GET['rid'];
```

pass it as hidden in view.php

```
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?> "/>
```

Make sure all your db connection goes perfect and echo all data whatever you want from row.